# std::filesystem::remove() how to check if it failed cause the file is missing?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm having this code:

```
std::error_code errc;

if (!std::filesystem::remove(entry.path(), errc)) {
   //check if it failed cause the file does not exist
}
```

Basically I'm trying to convert C code that did:

```
if (remove(e.entry.name) != 0) {
    if (errno == EEXIST)
       ...
}
```

Comment: _"Return value true if the file was deleted, false if it did not exist...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove

Comment: The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) says "[returns] false if it did not exist" is that not what's happening?

Comment: I believe [the answer you seek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code) is in `errc`.

Comment: @Tas No it's not, the documentation is not precise. The function will return true if the file was removed. If the file was not removed (for any reason, e.g. permission denied, or the file didn't exist) it returns false. I'm asking how do I check that remove() failed for one of the many cases it could fail.

Comment: @user4581301 You're apsolutely right. This question is asking how do I check for that specific error (file doesn't exist). Is there an errc somewhere in the standard libraries I can compare with ? Can I even compare errc with something using `==` ?

Comment: [`error_code::value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code/value) will give you the system-specific error code (assuming it'll fit in an `int`, something you can count on on all of today's major operating systems). `if (errc.value() == EEXIST)` ought to do what you want.

Comment: For portable code, you should pay attention (if implicitly) to the error_code's category, and to equivalent values from different categories.  `std::error_condition` was made for that.  You can compare your error_code to an error_condition like so:

`if (error == std::make_error_condition(std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory))`